# How to addmore fileds on form using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysqli

I have created form on their 3 fields is there customer name, contact and email
suppose to be if clicked submit button to addmore row so how would we do

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        </title></title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <form action="insert_customer.php" method="post"> 
            <table id="addrow"> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>Customer Name:</td> 
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="cust_name">
                    </td> 
                    <td>Contact:</td> 
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="contact"> 
                    <td>Email</td> 
                    <td>
                        <input type="email" name="email">
                    </td> 
                </tr> 
            </table> 

            <script> 
            function addrow(){ } 
            </script> 
            <p> 
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"> 
            <input type="button"name="Addmore" value="Addmore"/> </p> 
        </form> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Append` your table `addrow` with `jquery.append()`.

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        </title></title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <form action="insert_customer.php" method="post"> 
            <table id="addrow"> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>Customer Name:</td> 
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="cust_name">
                    </td> 
                    <td>Contact:</td> 
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="contact"> 
                    <td>Email</td> 
                    <td>
                        <input type="email" name="email">
                    </td> 
                </tr> 
            </table> 

            <p> 
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"> 
                <input type="button" id="add" name="Addmore" value="Addmore"/> 
            </p> 
        </form> 

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script> 
            $( "#add" ).click(function() {  
                    $("#addrow").append('<tr> <td>Customer Name:</td> <td><input type="text" name="cust_name"></td> <td>Contact:</td> <td><input type="text" name="contact"><td>Email</td> <td><input type="email" name="email"></td></tr> ');
            });
        </script> 

    </body> 
</html>
```

Since, you are having **multiple values** for `Customer Name`,`Contact`,`Email` . So, you have to use `name` as `array` type. Like below.

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        </title></title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <form action="insert_customer.php" method="post"> 
            <table id="addrow"> 
                <tr> 
                    <td>Customer Name:</td> 
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="cust_name[]">
                    </td> 
                    <td>Contact:</td> 
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="contact[]"> 
                    <td>Email</td> 
                    <td>
                        <input type="email" name="email[]">
                    </td> 
                </tr> 
            </table> 

            <p> 
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"> 
                <input type="button" id="add" name="Addmore" value="Addmore"/> 
            </p> 
        </form> 

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script> 
            $( "#add" ).click(function() {  
                    $("#addrow").append('<tr> <td>Customer Name:</td> <td><input type="text" name="cust_name[]"></td> <td>Contact:</td> <td><input type="text" name="contact[]"><td>Email</td> <td><input type="email" name="email[]"></td></tr> ');
            });
        </script> 

    </body> 
</html>
```

On user's request.

**insert_customer.php**

```
<?php

// Write Your Databse Connection.

$custName = $_POST['cust_name'];
$custContact = $_POST['contact'];
$custEmail = $_POST['email'];

$totalCustomerName = sizeof($custName);

for($i=0;$i<$totalCustomerName;$i++) {

    $customerName = $custName[$i];
    $customerContact = $custContact[$i];
    $customerEmail = $custEmail[$i];

    $sql ="insert into customer_info(cust_name,contact,email)values('$customerName',$customerContact,'$customerEmail')"; 

    // Run your query here.

}

?>
```

Comment: Be careful the OP have no Jquery tag.

Comment: thanks bro now from hereh ow i insert my records in mysql table custome_info

Comment: That's different question @Syedishtiyaqueahemad. You have to post that question separately. Or Search your question in stack overflow. There is lot of question & answer available in SO. Which will help you. If you think, this answer solved you problem. Please tick this answer as correct answer. As, it will help other user to find it easily. *Thanks*

Comment: yeah bro i thought u can help above code is executing well when im inserting my records and clicking submit button its getting error Array to string conversion

Comment: Yess. Because you are using array type. That's why. Yeah. I can help. Post your **insert_customer.php** code in your question. *Hurry up* @Syedishtiyaqueahemad

Comment: this is my query$sql ="insert into customer_info(cust_name,contact,email)values('$cust_name',$contact,'$email')";

Comment: if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$servername="localhost";
$uname="root";
$pwd="";
$db="employee";
$cust_name=$_POST['cust_name'];
$contact=$_POST['contact'];
$email=$_POST['email'];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $uname, $pwd, $db);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
//insert record in database customer_info
 $sql ="insert into customer_info(cust_name,contact,email)values('$cust_name',$contact,'$email')";
if($conn->query($sql)==true){
 echo "return true";
}
else{
 echo "unable to insert ";
}
}

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please have a look. And, What is the meaning of this *now help me fast*. I'm helping someone, not obeying their order @Syedishtiyaqueahemad *Allah Haafiz*

Comment: You didn't responded me back @Syedishtiyaqueahemad

Answer (score 0):

First you should add `onclick` event to the `addmore` button so it will trigger the function `addrow()'` when the user click :

```
<input type="button" name="Addmore" value="Addmore" onclick='addrow()'/>
```

Then you can append another column to the existing HTML element using `.innerHTML +=` :

```js
function addrow(){
    document.querySelector('#addrow tr').innerHTML += '<td>Address</td><td><input type="address" name="address"></td>';
}
```

```html
<form action="insert_customer.php" method="post"> 
  <table id="addrow"> 
    <tr> 
      <td>Customer Name:</td> 
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="cust_name">
      </td> 
      <td>Contact:</td> 
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="contact"> 
      <td>Email</td> 
      <td>
        <input type="email" name="email">
      </td> 
    </tr> 
  </table> 

  <p> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"> 
    <input type="button" name="Addmore" value="Addmore" onclick='addrow()'/> </p>
```